# What does padding do in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network

What does `padding` argument do in keras?

In NLP:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(xtrain, padding='')
```

In CNN:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(64,(3,3),padding=''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pad_sequences` it simply indicates whether sequences that are shorter than the specified max length (or, if unspecified, the length of the longest sequence in `xtrain`) are filled with the padding value in the beginning or in the end of the sequence (such as to attain the desired length).

With `Convolution2d` it indicates whether to pad (i.e. extend the tensor (e.g. pixel matrix or feature map) with additional rows and columns outside the border) or not.

I suggest looking into the respective documentations.